# Using of INDIRECT formula in many ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I'm standard excel user (I know only record macro :)), but I really need your help, I'm lost. I'll try to describe what I need to do.

I'm trying to apply limited drop-downs based on previous selection. Please find the picture:

Data (columns A, B)

Dropdowns (G, H)

What I need is, that the user select some, concrete Company in column G. He will have limited drop-down in H column. So everything, what I need, is using INDIRECT formula through the Data Validation (menu - Data), but for this I need to get name to every range in column B, which will be available (for same Company), so the name of these ranges have to have exact name for each Company (a, b, c ...etc.).

The problem is that I have hundreds Companies. Do you have some idea, how can I proceed macro which allocate these names to all ranges in B column with names as per A column?

If you have any other idea how I can solve this, it will be sufficient for me too.
Thanks.

[image: Picture]

Franta

Comment: You could use a `VLOOKUP` to [return multiple results](https://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values#536254) to generate a table that will be used for the second drop down.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach here is to use `OFFSET` for the Data Validation List formula.

In `H2` apply Data Validation List using

```
=OFFSET($B$1,MATCH($G2,$A:$A,0)-1,,COUNTIFS($A:$A,$G2),1)
```

What this does is:

- Finds the row containing the first instance of company in column `A` (`MATCH($G2,$A:$A,0)`)
- Counts the number of instances of company in column `A` (`COUNTIFS($A:$A,$G2)`)
- Creates a range offset from `B1` by the Row match -1, and resizes it to the count of company
- That's the range used by Validation

<sub>Note: this relies on the companies being sorted as shown in your sample data</sub>